# ASP.net frame work 4 web application throws exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, out-of-memory, 32bit-64bit

I have a optimization application which is data heavy. I am also multi-threading.

As I increase data size I receive error

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in xxx.DLL
>   but was not handled in user code.

Machine has enough unused memory, My plugins are able to handle the work load if run separately. It gotta be ASP.net that causes the error.

I tried to force the application to be built as 64 bit, but got an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'xxx' or one of its dependencies. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

How can I get rid of these memory issues? If I remove multi-threading the application is running fine but very slow.

Comment: Make sure all of your dependencies are 64-bit or platform-neutral.

Comment: What is your app *doing*? Genuine question. Is it doing graphics processing, for example? Or Office automation? If so, it is possible the problem isn't actually *memory* - but *handles*. Which usually means you aren't `using` things correctly (pun not intentional). BTW, neither of those use-cases is supported, technically speaking. We can't offer much advice without knowing what is going on... We aren't psychic.

Comment: Are you hosting this in Azure Websites by chance?

Comment: You might want to post (a piece of) the relevant code that causes the error. It will probably help others to understand the problem. Hence the question "what is your app doing".

Comment: [...optimization application which is data heavy. I am also multi-threading...][... Remove multi-threading .. Is running fine.. but slow...] signs that tell me that [...gotta be ASP.net that causes...] seems not likely. Just a symptom but not the cause.